# Clicking first element of drop down menu that is not a SELECT element -Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a drop down menu that I haven't been able to figure out how to click the first element for. It is not a `SELECT` element, so I have been clicking the drop down, waiting for elements to be visible, and then try selecting the first option. That has not been working, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
driver.get("https://bi.prozorro.org/sense/app/2595af2b-985f-4771-aa36-2133e1f89df0/sheet/48781d08-1fce-489b-af05-34c253e95ec2/state/analysis#view/pEh")

#click for menu to appear
tenderercode=WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='title ng-binding']")))
tenderercode.click()
sleep(3)

#entering text in menu
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search in listbox']")
element.click()
element.send_keys("test")

#click on first element  
first=WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                "body.qv-client.qv-sheet-enabled.qv-view-sheet:nth-child(2) div.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope div.lui-popover-container.ng-scope div.qv-listbox-popover.ng-scope.lui-popover div.lui-nopad.lui-popover__body.ng-scope div.listbox-wrapper.ng-scope div.qv-object-wrapper.ng-isolate-scope article.qv-object.qvt-visualization.qv-layout-xsmall.qv-object-listbox.qv-selections-active div.qv-inner-object div.qv-object-content-container:nth-child(4) div.qv-object-content.ng-isolate-scope div.qv-listbox-container.ng-scope.qv-listbox-interactive div.qv-listbox-wrapper.searchActive div.qv-listbox-scroll-area.qv-animate.ng-isolate-scope.qv-listbox-virtual-scroll-enabled div.scroll-content:nth-child(1) ul.qv-listbox.ng-scope > li.qv-listbox-item.ng-scope.serverOptional:nth-child(1)")))

first.click()
```

Error: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

The timeout error makes me think my css selector is incorrect, but I've tried the xpath too, and that hasn't fared much better. A little bit at my wits end, so any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Add e link to your page or html code

Comment: The elink is in the first line of the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
first=WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "your locator")))
first.click()
```

to

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "your locator")))
first = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("your locator")
first.click()
```

And fix locator. It is not the main issue, but it's also the problem.

**Update.** I also find one more locator.
To find the first item use the locator use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".qv-listbox-item.serverOptional:nth-of-type(1)>.qv-listbox-text>span")
```

To click use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".qv-listbox-item.serverOptional:nth-of-type(1)>.qv-listbox-text>span>span")
```

Comment: Ah, yes sorry rookie mistake. I fixed the format, but still getting the timeout error

Comment: What do you mean by fix the locator? I’ve tried the code with the xpath, but haven’t had much luck. Are there other options I should try?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Do you mind if I ask how you found that locator?

Comment: I found it with my big experience. Google css selectors. Удачи